# Overwrite function javascript in child window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I open a window by :
`var popup =window.open(url,'Image', 'directories=no,height=640,location=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=no,toolbar=no,width=680');`

in child window opened have function OpenFile(url);
Can i Overwrite this function in parent window? or bind click event to element in child window from parent window (because i can't edit child page).
Parent and child window in same domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how i would make it:

```
var popup =window.open(url,'Image', 'directories=no,height=640,location=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=no,toolbar=no')

function waitOnloadWindow(){
    var body = popup.document.getElementsByTagName("body");
    // Not loaded yet
    if(!body[0] || !popup.OpenFile){
        setTimeout(waitOnloadWindow, 50);
    }else{
        // Replace child window function here
        popup.OpenFile = function(url){ alert('replaced');}
    }
}
waitOnloadWindow();
```

A more generic way (if you have more than one function to replace) :

```
function replaceWindowFunction(win, fnName, fnFunction) {
    var body = popup.document.getElementsByTagName("body");

    if(!body[0] || !popup[fnName]){ // Wait for loading
        setTimeout(function() {
            replaceWindowFunction(win, fnName, fnFunction);
        }, 50);
    }else{
        // Replace child window function here
        popup[fnName] = fnFunction;
    }
}

// Usage:
var popup = window.open("test.html",'Image', 'directories=no,height=640,location=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=no,toolbar=no')
replaceWindowFunction(popup, 'OpenFile', function() { alert('replaced'); } );
```

Comment: I update the code. The correct test to see if the chid document is loaded is to check if body and popup.OpenFile function exists both before replacing it